# Change body background on link mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need your help...already read all solution but nothing suit to my needs.
I use Hamburger menu, when the menu clicked and the body closed by other background full monitor size also all the link on it.

I want to change the background when the mouse over the link and each link have different background. **For example:** when the mouse over link About then the BG change to boy.jpg and when the mouse over to menu Service then the BG change to man.jpg and when the mouse not over the link then the BG return to default BG image.

Here the menu code

```css
body:after {
  background-image:url(../images/AboutEMC.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0;
  top:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transition:all .4s ease;
  transition:all .4s ease;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="b-nav">
  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="about.html">About EMC</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="service.html">Service</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="case1.html">Portfolio</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="team.html">Hire Us</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="news.html">News</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better to check if you add a fiddle example from your code

Answer (score 0):

You just try this..

```
$('a.class').on('mousein', function(){
   $('#portfolio').css('background-image', 'url("other.jpg")');
});
$('a.class').on('mouseout', function(){, function(){
  $('#portfolio').css('background-image', 'url("woman.jpg")');
});
```

Comment: Where i can put this script? on each <li> ?

Comment: @karthicknagarajan this wont work. Ther  is no element with a.class, you should use a.b-link

Answer (score 0):

I would add in the filename you'd want to switch into the html as an attribute...

```
<body data-img="default.jpg">

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" data-img="boy.jpg" href="about.html">About EMC</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" data-img="girl.jpg" href="about.html">About EMC</a>
  </li>

</body>
```

Then add your javascript to switch them...

jQuery

```
$('a.b-link').on('mousein', function(){
   var newUrl = '../img/' + $(this).data('data-img'),
   $('body').css('background-image', 'url(newUrl)');
});

$('a.b-link').on('mouseout', function(){, function(){
   var oldUrl = '../img/' + $('body').data('data-img'),
   $('body').css('background-image', 'url(oldUrl)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your class name (different from each other) and try this with different images.

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b-link").mouseover(function(){
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/help/html/demo/files/demo/bubbles64.png)");
    });

});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `data` attribute mechanism. In your case as you have requirements like to show different image on each link then you need to define which image to be shown,

```
<body data-img="default.jpg">
  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="about.html" data-image="about.jpg">About EMC</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="service.html" data-image="service.jpg">Service</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="case1.html" data-image="portfolio.jpg">Portfolio</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="team.html" data-image="hire.jpg">Hire Us</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="b-link" href="news.html" data-image="news.jpg">News</a>
  </li>

</body>
```

In jQuery do like this,

```
$('a.b-link').on('mousein', function(){
   var img = $(this).data("image");
   $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ img +')');
});

$('a.b-link').on('mouseout', function(){, function(){
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url("default.jpg")');
});
```